# Можно ли повторять личные местоимения в следующем предложении?

Tags: местоимения, тавтология

Допустим ли повтор личного местоимения "Я" в следующем предложении, если в предыдущем оно уже использовалось?

> Я снова сидел в покачивающейся лодочке, а посверкивающие звёзды,
> прекрасно дополнявшие лунный пейзаж, освещали впереди болтающуюся
> путеводную позолоту. Нить всё ещё ожидала меня и я снова отправился за
> ней.

Я всячески стараюсь избегать повторов тех или иных слов сразу же в следующем предложении, так как чувствую, будто это отдаёт тавтологией. С этим и хочу узнать, насколько приемлемо не только в данном случае, но и вообще повторять личные местоимения в следующих предложениях?

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что в вашем тексте нет перебора с местоимениями.
Сравните, вот "я" и "меня" у классиков.

> Под конец — покойно, с любопытством даже — я стал ждать часа, когда омерзение к самому себе пересилит привычку — пить, есть, курить табак, ходить, добывать деньги и прочее...
> Помню, одиннадцатого мая, утром я начал, как обычно, бриться и — швырнул бритву на умывальник. Час мой стукнул: не желаю. Я вышел на улицу и в ювелирном магазине продал часы и кольцо, — все, что у меня было. Затем я сел на улице под лавровым деревцом, выпил кофе, спросил у гарсона пачку юмористических журналов. Прежде чем их читать, я быстро решил: кончу сегодня, на рассвете, на мосту Инвалидов. Первый раз за много лет кофе казался так вкусен и журналы так забавны. Я развлекался, как мог, весь день.
> А. Н. Толстой. Мираж

> Я открываю глаза. Ветер закинул мне на лицо полу Алешкиной шинели, колено у меня раскрыто, мы едем по голому насту, и терция колокольчиков слышнехонько звучит в воздухе с своей дребезжащей квинтой.
> Я смотрю, где стоги; но вместо стогов, уже с открытыми глазами, вижу какой-то дом с балконом и зубчатую стену крепости. Меня мало интересует рассмотреть хорошенько этот дом и крепость: мне, главное, хочется опять видеть белый коридор, по которому я бежал, слышать звон церковного колокола и целовать руку старичка. Я снова закрываю глаза и засыпаю.
> Л. Н. Толстой. Метель

Во втором предложении по правилам перед союзом "и" необходима запятая. Это сложносочиненное предложение, в котором две основы:
***Нить** всё ещё **ожидала** меня, и **я** снова **отправился** за ней.*

Маринка уже ждала меня, и я снова стал спиной к убитой лошади и полетел над землей. [Константин Воробьев. Крик (1962)]

И еще. Вряд ли *посверкивающие* звезды могут что-то освещать.
[Посверкивать](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mas/50235/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%CC%81%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) — время от времени, слегка сверкать.
Может быть, лучше использовать слова *мерцающие*, или *сверкающие*, или *сияющие*.

*Белое судно легко шло вперёд, плавно покачиваясь на зыбких волнах, звёзды мерцали высоко над водой, освещая сквозь набегающие облака тёмную водную гладь* (Р. Малыбаева. Двое в море).

Comment: Извините, что пишу с таким запозданием. Спасибо, что привели отличные примеры, однако я не привык равняться на орфографию классиков. Они писали по другим законам; сейчас правила немного изменились; ориентироваться на пунктуацию и грамматику в других книгах стало проблематичным, так как не знаешь, чем руководствуется тот или иной писатель. Единственное что остаётся - это преодолевать собственный идеализм (учиться употреблять личные местоимения не через предложение ) и изучать современные заповеди русского языка.

Comment: Дело удивительное! _...я не привык равняться на орфографию классиков..._ М-м, а на **что** же Вы ориентируетесь? Вижу только один явный недочет: в первом предложении имеется "я снова", во втором — тоже. Но может, это задумка такая (контекста-то нет)? Из песни Е. Ваенги: _Снова стою одна, снова курю, мама, снова, а вокруг тишина, взятая за основу_. Не классика, конечно, но большинство подпевает, не оглядываясь на Толстых...

Comment: У классиков тоже бывают ошибки (хоть и крайне редко). Многое устарело с XIX века. Например, использование *не ..., но* вместо *не ..., а*.

Comment: Согласна:  у всех могут быть ошибки. Не согласна: А. Н. Толстой — это XX век.

Answer (score 0):

Розенталь:
Тавтология — повторение в предложении **однокоренных** слов.
https://classes.ru/grammar/114.Rosental/18-t/html/unnamed_1.html

Исходя из этого, "я" и "меня" не похоже на тавтологию. О следующих предложениях речи не идёт.

"Посверкивающие звёзды", скорее всего, освещали не посвёркиванием (просто характеристика), а свечением, которое подразумевается.

С точки зрения звучания, играет роль то, сколько слов между повторяющимися местоимениями. В данном случае — много. До прочтения второго "я" первое уже стирается из оперативной памяти.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. "Мерцающие" и впрямь звучит логичнее 

Comment: _"Мерцающие" и впрямь звучит логичнее._ Конечно. Именно это определение я предложила Вам в своем ответе (не _oleedd_). Успехов Вам, Джин!

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Да, тоже не понял этот комментарий, который, скорее всего вам адресован. Но у вас тоже имеется комментарий автора, что странно. Как так можно промахнуться?